# Unable to compile java files to class files for hadoop

Tags: java, hadoop, hadoop2

I am using hadoop 2.6.4 and trying to compile java file using the following command:

```
javac -classpath $HADOOP_HOME/share/hadoop/common/hadoop-common-2.6.4.jar:$HADOOP_HOME/share/hadoop/mapreduce/hadoop-mapreduce-client-core-2.6.4.jar:$HADOOP_HOME/share/hadoop/common/lib/commons-cli-1.2.jar -d class_files *.java
```

But this is not compiling the files due to missing hadoop packages:

```
GraphSearch.java:28: error: package org.apache.hadoop.conf does not exist
import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configured;
                         ^
GraphSearch.java:29: error: package org.apache.hadoop.fs does not exist
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;
                       ^
GraphSearch.java:30: error: package org.apache.hadoop.io does not exist
import org.apache.hadoop.io.IntWritable;
                       ^
GraphSearch.java:31: error: package org.apache.hadoop.io does not exist
import org.apache.hadoop.io.LongWritable;
                       ^
GraphSearch.java:32: error: package org.apache.hadoop.io does not exist
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
                       ^
GraphSearch.java:33: error: package org.apache.hadoop.mapred does not exist
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.*;
^
GraphSearch.java:34: error: package org.apache.hadoop.util does not exist
import org.apache.hadoop.util.Tool;
                         ^
GraphSearch.java:35: error: package org.apache.hadoop.util does not exist
import org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner;
                         ^
GraphSearch.java:52: error: cannot find symbol
public class GraphSearch extends Configured implements Tool {
```

Tried setting the classpath using the following command, not sure whether its correct:

```
export CLASSPATH=$CLASSPATH:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/hadoop-common-2.6.4.jar:$/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/hadoop-mapreduce-client-core-2.6.4.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/commons-cli-1.2.jar
```

Kindly help!

Comment: Try `ls $HADOOP_HOME/share/hadoop/common/hadoop-common-2.6.4.jar` -- does it display the jar's file name, or tell you it doesn't exist?

Comment: It says it doesn't exist.

Comment: But via GUI I can see it present in that directory!

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
export PATH=$PATH:$HADOOP_HOME/bin

javac -cp $(hadoop classpath) -d class_files *.java
```

short and sweet but make sure you have already set HADOOP_HOME env variable.

Comment: run command `hadoop classpath` and check the output it should print the all jar and classpath entry for hadoop also share the output so we can figure out if any jar is missing?

Comment: hduser@Ubuntu:/home/saud$ hadoop classpath'
/usr/local/hadoop/etc/hadoop:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/*:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/*:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/*:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/*:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/*:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/*:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/*:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/*:/contrib/capacity-scheduler/*.jar                                                                        Looks like all the required ones are present

Answer (score 0):

This is because there are classes missing in your hadoop jar files.
Download the jar file from here:
[Hadoop pre built jar](https://github.com/ishitvyas/hadoop-hipi-prebuilt-jar/blob/master/hipi-2.1.0.jar)

replace it in core/build/libs folder